# Retrieving the action-instance-id from Facebook given the URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

### tl;dr: No, there isn't a way.

---

Calling `publish_action` using the JS SDK is actually pretty straightforward. However (from the little info I gleaned from reading the documentation), there's no way for me to *query* facebook to have it return the action instance ID for an object that I have already published... is there?

Example:

User A loads the page, and the page sends an `FB.api` call to `/me/news.reads`, which returns an action instance ID.

User A reloads the page, and the page again sends an `FB.api` call to `/me/news.reads`, but this time, the Graph API returns:

```
{
    error: {
        code: 3501,
        message: 'blahblahblah... already associated... blah blah'
        type: 'OAuthException'
    }
}
```

Pretty standard stuff, and expected, since I turned off the ability to publish the same URL multiple times.

Now then, is there any way for me to retrieve a previously published action instance ID from the Graph API by passing in the URL, or is it up to me to handle the returned action instance ID (from the original publication attempt) and save it to a database? I was hoping I wouldn't have to do that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to retrieve instances of published actions other than:

- Accessing action by `id`:
  `http://graph.facebook.com/ACTION_ID`
- Accessing all instances published by specific user:
  `http://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/NAMESPACE:ACTION` (`NAMESPACE:ACTION` may be replaces by the name of one of [built-in actions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/) like `news.reads`, `music.listend`, etc.

If you want to access details of published actions connected/referencing specific object you'll need to save that data on your end for later usage.

Comment: Unfortunate, but I figured I'd ask. Thanks for your help.